# NativeScript v7+ with Vue Firebase Integration Can't resolve tns-core-modules/application/application

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

My app is on NS 7.1.1 using @nativescript/firebase: 11.1.3 and  nativescript-plugin-firebase: 10.6.3 while building I'm getting Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/application/application' as the package is renamed and changed a bit but this issue is coming from node_modules folder. i'm also using @nativescript/core : 7.0.13.

please help if you have a solution to this

Comment: did you try import like 'import * as application from "@nativescript/core/application";' ?

Comment: do i need to update node_module files accordingly? importing it does not help.

Comment: check this https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/1675

Comment: tried, nothing helps

Answer (score 0):

**Plugin version 11+ works with NativeScript 7+.**

Usage:

```
import {firebase} from '@nativescript/firebase';
```

**Plugin version 10.0.0 works with NativeScript 6.1+. Using an older version? Stick to plugin version < 10.**

Usage:

```
const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
```